# How to set up varnish with two backends?

Tags: varnish

I have installed Apache and Tomcat, and want to install Varnish in front of them , static goes to Apache and dynamic goes to Tomcat ( all /static/* url goes to Apache and should be cached by Varnish, other urls goes to tomcat).

How to configure Varnish ?

```
backend static {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}
backend dynamic {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8081";
}
sub vcl_recv {
 if (req.url ~ "^/static/") { # How to determine which backend to go to, and cache it?
    return (lookup);         # return (static.lookup)?
 } else {
    return (lookup);
 }
 return (lookup);
}
```

Comment: You can just set the backends per Kekkis' answer, there is no need for the return(lookup): lines. The default VCL will be appended and has that.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Varnish documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html), use

```
set req.backend = static;
```

and so on.